# How To Get a User's Role with a DiscordSocketClient

Tags: c#, .net, roles, discord, discord.net

I have been locking for a long time on how to get a user's role so I can set permissions for commands.  This is my code.  I am using Discord.NET in the newer version.

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AmberScript2.Modules
{
    public class Kick : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("kick")]
        public async Task KickUser(string userName)
        {
            if (Context.Guild.GetRole(Context.Message.Author.Id).Name == "Administrator")
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Success!");
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Inadequate permisions.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error i am getting is object reference not set to an instance of an object.  I have been trying to find the source of it and i can't.  Thanks.

(And yes i have yet to get rid of excess usings.  This code isn't done yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to try to get a role of the user, try using SocketGuildUser instead of a string. (Use var role = (user as IGuildUser).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Role");)

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AmberScript2.Modules
{
    public class Kick : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("kick")]
        public async Task KickUser(SocketGuildUser userName)
        {
             var user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
             var role = (user as IGuildUser).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Role");
             if (!userName.Roles.Contains(role))
             {
            // Do Stuff
            if (user.GuildPermissions.KickMembers)
            {
            await userName.KickAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

That is most of my code for kicking.

Answer (score 3):

With the line RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers) you check whether or not the user has the permission to kick members.

Within GuildPermission there are many different permissions. 
Like GuildPermission.ManageRoles etc.

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AmberScript2.Modules
{
    public class Kick : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("kick"), RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)]
        public async Task KickUser(SocketGuildUser userName)
        {
             var user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
             var role = (user as IGuildUser).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Role");
             if (!userName.Roles.Contains(role))
             {
            // Do Stuff
            if (user.GuildPermissions.KickMembers)
            {
            await userName.KickAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...
To my knowledge Linq needs to be used with IGuildUser or SocketGuildUser.
I have not yet been able to create functioning code to check if the person performing the command does have a role named "Admin"or some other name
Edit: This might be helpful
https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuildUser.html

Comment: Please try to add some sample code, details in your answer.